# Can aria-describedby or aria-details reference an element inside of an iframe?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is it possible for `aria-describedby` or `aria-details` to reference an element inside of an iframe? This example html shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```html
<!-- This element links to an element in the current document and is properly announced as: "Outer details" -->
<div tabindex="0" aria-describedby="details-outer" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
</div>

<!-- This element attempts to link to an element in iframe, which is not picked up -->
<div tabindex="0" aria-describedby="details-inner" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
</div>

<div id='details-outer'>Outer details</div>

<iframe id="frame" srcdoc="<p id='details-inner'>Inner details</p>"></iframe>
```

Note that I'm using `aria-describedby` here since support for `aria-details` seems pretty spotty at the moment.

If this is not possible, what are the alternatives I can use to have screenreaders announce content from inside an iframe when an element in the top level page is focused?

Comment: Is the iframe on the exact same domain (no subdomains, not someone elses domain). If not you have next to no control as iframes are essentially sandboxed (and if you do have control we will probably have to jump through a load of hoops).

Comment: Same domain for this specific question but I'd be interested in both cases

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the given approach: The doc in an iframe is not the same doc that contains that iframe, which means that you cannot query the element with its id.

You can instead use a little hefty javascript to load the content of your inner doc into your outer doc -- one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I agree with the comments that the `<iframe>` is sandboxed.  I could have several `<iframe>` elements with each one having an element with `id="details-inner">` and it would be perfectly valid.  It's not considered a duplicate ID issue since each iframe is its own document.  If you used `aria-describedby` or `aria-labelledby` and tried to point to "details-inner", the screen reader would not know which ID to use.

If you try to validate your HTML code, plugging in your example code o https://validator.w3.org/nu, you get this error:

```
Error: The aria-describedby attribute must point to an element in the same document.
```

A possible workaround is to use `aria-label` instead.  There is no equivalent to `aria-describedby` that lets you specify a literal string.  (There isn't an `aria-description` analogous to `aria-labelledby` and `aria-label`.  Don't use `aria-roledescription` because that's for a different purpose.)

Anyway, you can set the `aria-label` to the `innerText` of the element in your iframe.  Something like this:

```js
    yourElement.setAttribute('aria-label', document.getElementById("frame").getElementById("details-inner").innerText);
```

where `yourElement` is the object handle of your second `<div>`.